# Language of the operating system?

Tags: internationalization, lua

Is there a way to get the language of the running operating system? I would like to be able to change the language of the program when it starts.

Comment: If you want to follow i18n best practices, you should not ***change*** the language when application starts, you should select ***User's*** language on application's start. As you see from answers below, there is no standard multi-platform of doing this in LUA. To make matters worse, there are differences in OS native functions and OS LCID on Windows ***is not*** what you are looking for, you are looking for User LCID (trust me, it might differ).

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I'll let the user select his favourite language, that's the best solution at all. Thank all of you!

Comment: No, it is the worst solution at all. Imagine that all the applications in your system would do that - they will basically force you to choose language all the time (or even at the first start). I don't know about you, but in my case you would hear a lot of f-words in such circumstances. There are reasons why Operating Systems have Regional Preferences settings - so you can select your preferences once. In terms of LUA, I am pretty sure that somebody wrote some nice script to detect the language, just Google it.

Comment: You're right, but it won't be a huge problem when you ask once for the user's prefered language, or? Then you could save it in a *.ini or whatever. Many setups for programs ask or also other software at the first start. By the way, I use Google everytime before I ask, but I didn't have much luck searching. But I'll give it again a try. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's platform specific and beyond the cope of Lua's standard library. In *some* cases you may be able to figure it out from `getenv` or something, but you can't rely on that in a cross platform way.

You could write a little extension module that you port to the various platforms you need to support which gives you that info for a particular operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
     print(os.setlocale(nil));
```

can give you the needed information, though you likely need to parse it a bit. Or you could access the proper env var, e.g.

```
    print(os.getenv("LANG"));
```

gives en_GB.utf8 on my system, so you can deduce my system "talks" english.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get "nil" when I try it with os.getenv. Is there maybe another way to solve this?

Comment: that envar is not set but on "*nix" systems (it could on windows too, but if you see nil, it is not!); if you are on windows, you can try a system specific way, like digging the register or using some API (GetUserDefaultLangID should do); then of course your program won't be portable. I don't know if lua has a "win32" module